# How to obtain OAuth access token for frontend-only apps with similar capabilities to client credentials?

Tags: oauth

So I can use client credentials OAuth grant type to obtain an access token on the backend which gives bearer access in the name of the client itself.

How can I obtain such a token for a frontend-only app which cannot hold credentials? What I imagine is some flow where I first call authorization endpoint and that one redirects back to registered/trusted redirection URL, and then I obtain access token from the token endpoint. All that using PKCE. The main difference would be that there is no user involved in authorization endpoint redirect, no user consent, nothing.

Is this something standard?

Answer (score 1):

I realized this makes no sense. While it is true that redirect helps authenticate the app, you cannot trust the frontend user to not be malicious and misuse the token obtain by the app in their browser. So or you have frontend act in the name of the user, or you route the request through the backend which verifies the request, and then issues a call in the name of the app (client).